# get a heap dump from a JRE only on Windows

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump, heap-profiling

Our product runs on our customer's servers with only a JRE(no JDK) on Windows.

I know that I can get a heap dump on OutOfMemoryError through a flag.

However, is there a way to get a heap dump from the JRE JVM process proactively ?

I was planning on getting a few healthy heap dumps and compare them with the heap dump obtained on OutOfMemoryError.

Preferably, I should be able to ask the customer to download this tool/utility and then run it on the server to obtain the heap dump at will.

I tried [jvisualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/download.html) however jvisualvm would not list our product jVM. It would only list some of the JVMs running at that time and not all the JVMs running at that time. PLUS jvisualvm is very bulky.

P.S : Are there 3rd party utilities that can be executed on the host of JVM to dump the heap ? Also, customer cannot upgrade the JRE at this point of time. And none of the answers to the previous question are selected as answer!

Thank you,

Comment: I saw that question. Given that question was asked 2 years ago, I'm looking to see if there are utilities, etc that can get the task done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To dump heap from within JVM, use `com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean`:

   ```
       HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean hs =
               ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
       hs.dumpHeap("/path/to/heapdump.bin", false);
   ```
2. To dump heap of another process from outside, use [HotSpot Dynamic Attach mechanism](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#battach).
   I wrote a tiny utility for that, see https://github.com/apangin/jattach.

   Build the program with `make` and then run

   ```
   jattach <PID> dumpheap /path/to/heapdump.bin
   ```

Comment: does jattach dump a .hprof ?

Comment: I tried building on cygwin/windows but could not get it to build. am creating issue for same in github.

Comment: @anjanb Yes, it dumps .hprof, exactly as jmap does. I've added jattach implementation for Windows.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it and let you know if it works for me.